# What's the best way to add a specific user-based context to every page in a project

Tags: python, django

To give the question some context, let's say I have 10 views with each view function decorated to include extra context, but I want this context to be in all views (see the problem below). Is there a better way to do this instead of putting the decorator on every view function? It just seems silly/repetitive to have the decorator around every view in my project, especially when the number of views is large and keeps increasing. Could I implement a custom template tag in my base.html which is shared in every template, and therefore have only one place where this user-specific context is evaluated? Is this acceptable/bad practice? Thanks for your help!

The problem in a views.py:

```
@add_extra_context()
def view_1(request)

...

@add_extra_context()  # silly!
def view_1000(request)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

[Context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Comment: thanks this helped, but led to another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996680/is-it-possible-to-check-whether-a-context-variable-is-already-set-in-a-view-withi